# Windows Server - Redirecting Requests for Public IP to Localhost

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I have a client that has a Windows Server 2008 box running two different set of scripts.

One set of scripts is hosting several websites under several different domains. The other set of scripts is used to generate reports and other information based on the URLs in the first set.

The second set of scripts (for reporting) generate the reports based on the URL. However, the reports hang (don't work) *unless* the URLs are manually entered into the server's HOSTS file and tied to `127.0.0.1`. Otherwise, it seems that the requests are going to the external IP address, which may be getting stuck at the DMZ / firewall. 
 Updating the HOSTS file is cumbersome for the client.

My suggestion, aside from editing rules in the DMZ, is to update the Windows Routing Table, so that any requests destined for the public IP address automatically get rerouted to `127.0.0.1`.

Am I crazy, and/or is this a stupid suggestion?  Can this be accomplished with the `route add` command? If so, exactly how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems that the requests are going to the external IP address, which
>   may be getting stuck at the DMZ / firewall.
>
> [...]
>
> My suggestion, aside from editing rules in the DMZ, is to update the
>   Windows Routing Table, so that any requests destined for the public IP
>   address automatically get rerouted to 127.0.0.1.

The rule of professional system administration is to make standard systems work standard. It's unexpected for your server to not be able to resolve it's own name and/or access it's own interface's IP address. I don't know your topology, however, and there could be hairpin NAT at play or some kind of SNAT/DNAT above the server. Whatever the reason, at least work to discern the cause of it all and if it's a standards-driven environment.

Nevertheless, moving away from theory and into practical matters, you need to take traces of the traffic right down to the peaks and valleys of electrical impulses on the wire if you have to, all in order to find out why that server can't talk to it's own interface's address. Masking the stench with HOSTS files entries and crazy routes in the routing table will come back to torture you later.

The answer to the problem cannot be given because the needed facts aren't given, but the methodology would be:

- Listen on each interface involved in the communication (server, switch, firewall, etc.)
- Check each network hop for applications and services that could interfere with traffic
- That includes multiple layers on each host. Just because your host firewall isn't killing the conversation, doesn't mean IIS isn't tanking once the packets get past the TCP/IP stack.
- On a Windows host, [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) is your best punctilious packet parsing playmate.

> Am I crazy, and/or is this a stupid suggestion?

No comment. =)

> Can this be accomplished with the route add command? If so, exactly
>   how?

From the perspective of "What is the least productive way to accomplish this task that is simultaneously most likely to make me want to commit seppuku with a spork", yes it could be done. As for "exactly how", I won't tell you lest I beat you to the spork.